# How do I select current database name and all the schema for the database name in SYBASE ASE using a query

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

How do I select current database name and all the schema for the database name in SYBASE ASE using a query

tried Select db_name

gives invalid column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current database:

```
select db_name()
```

By 'schema' I'm assuming you mean a user (in the database) who owns at least one object:

```
select distinct(user_name(uid)) from sysobjects
```

**NOTE:** I'm not sitting in front of an ASE instance at the moment so can't recall, or verify, if the 2nd query could generate a `NULL` ... should be easy enough to test and add an optional `where` clause to filter out as needed